# How to add Magento CMS PAGES to topMenu (not in top.links) in Magento 1.7.2

Tags: php, magento, hyperlink

I want to add Magento CMS PAGES to topMenu (not in top.links) in my custom template in Magento 1.7.2

So I created a file called **local.xml** in the path

**app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/local.xml**

The content in the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">   
      <reference name="topMenu">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label> TEST </label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title> TEST </title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>1</position></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This XML supposed to create a link called **TEST** in the **topMenu** that connects with "customer/getAccountUrl"

but it doesnt appear my link...Anybody suspects what it might be wrong?

Comment: The same exact code runs with "top.links" instead of "topMenu" but this is not what I want...I need to appear the TEST cms link to the topMenu...Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new links to CMS pages like this:

app/design/frontend/default/theme/layout/customer.xml (About line 49)

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>60</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Corporate Orders</label><url>http://www.yourdomain.com/corporate-orders.html</url><title>Corporate Orders</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>50</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Delivery</label><url>http://www.yourdomain.com/delivery.html</url><title>Delivery</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>40</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Contact Us</label><url>http://www.yourdomain.com/contact-us.html</url><title>Contact Us</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>20</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Customer Service</label><url>http://www.yourdomain.com/customer-service.html</url><title>Customer Service</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>30</position></action>   
    </reference>
```

This is an example of what I have on my site on Magento 1.6.1, but I cannot see how this could be different on 1.7.2.